# In Batman: Arkham Asylum for Windows Live, how do I get back to offline profile?

Tags: batman-arkham-asylum, games-for-windows-live

I have been playing this game to around 50% when I got this stupid idea: why not create a GFWL account.

Now all my save game slots are empty and I can't manage to get my previous save game.

I've tried to copy/paste my old save game but the game told me that it is corrupted...

Is there a way to get back to the good old offline mode and continue my adventure ?

If not, does the same thing will happend to my other GFWL games ?

Answer (score 4):

I recently had to move my save games around and here is what worked for me:

1. Create a new game and make sure that it autosaves (this happens as soon as the first cut scene is over)
2. Exit the game completely - this is important because if you don't it will still try to access the old game.
3. Navigate to the save folder - probably something like 'Eidos/Batman Arkham Asylum/SaveData/019243000000/' <- the last folder will be different but you get the point
4. You'll see a save0.sgd file in that folder.  Replace that with your actual save file (you may have to rename your save to save0.sgd) - the file size is usually about 60kb or so.
5. Restart the game.

Hopefully this will work for you.

Comment: I already tried this, but the game told me that my save game is 'corrupted'...

Comment: Dude - I'm sorry to hear that.  I guess the question is if the file is actually corrupted or if that is just the error you get when you try to load a non-GFWL save game.  There are plenty of downloadable save games to be found on cheat sites and no one really seems to mention an error so it sounds like your save might actually be corrupted.  :(